# How do I set up Python3 as the default Python version on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 installed, and I can access either by typing "python" or "python3".

However, when I try to install the latest version of Django with `pip install Django==2.0.4`, Python 2.7 is detected and the highest version that can be installed is version 1.11, since Django 2.0.4 requires Python3.

**In summary**

I need the default version of Python on my machine to be Python3, and I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Using an alias won't work, since I'm trying to make it so that other apps detect the correct version. My `which python` result should be Python3.

**Assumed Answer**

I would imagine that I need to edit my Path in a way that prefers Python3 over Python 2, but I'm unsure of how to do so. When I type `echo $PATH` I get `/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. I'm not sure if that helps or not.

Any ideas on what to do? Also, I'd prefer for Python3 to be the *default*, so I'd rather not use a virtualenv.

edit:

Just kidding, not solved. So pip3 installs Django2. But when I run Django2, I see that it's still relying on Python2.7. Here's the error:

```
File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)

 from django.conf.urls import url, include, path
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

Comment: `pip` is python2 btw and `pip3` is for python3

Comment: Don't meddle with default Python installation, it's necessary to OSX as a whole. Just call using `python3` and `pip3` or use specific environments, with their symlinks.

Comment: @JeanRostan actually apple recommends developers update python, ruby, and perl in the [developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/FileSystemProtections/FileSystemProtections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH2-DontLinkElementID_2)

Comment: @GrantWilliams it explicity says in your link to manage your own installations of the language in `/usr/local/`, it seems to me they're saying, don't use system language, manage your own environment as I wrote. OSX Python and other distributions are either in `/usr/bin` or `system/library`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this  https://www.maketecheasier.com/using-python-3-on-mac/amp/ and you will get your answer.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the OS, in windows you need to add the directory to which python is installed and to your system path and then you can change the name of the python.exe file. `in the python 2 install location python.exe should be called python2.exe and in the python3 install location the file python.exe should remain unchanged.` This way you can access python2 or python3 from the command line with python2 and python respectively.

Comment: On unix you could add alias's as needed to get the behavior you want  `alias python="python3"`